# Перевод Даты в секунды

Tags: javascript, jquery, время

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно перевести в секунды (секунды с 1 января 1970 года) форматы дат типа `00:56:20 11.10.17`. Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

Формат, содержащий секунды от 1 января 1970 года называется **unix timestamp**. В javascript для преобразования можно использовать объект Date. Например, метод **parse** принимает дату в виде строки и возвращает время в милисекундах. В итоге для получения секунд его потребуется разделить еще на 1000:

```js
const second = Date.parse('2017.10.11 10:56:20')/1000;
console.log(second);
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, то что нужно)

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего это сделать с помощью библиотеки Moment.js:

```
moment('00:56:20 11.10.17', 'HH:mm:ss DD.MM.YY').unix();
```

Comment: Однозначно проще. Библиотека позволяет задать кастомный формат.

Answer (score 0):

Метод `Date.parse()` должен принимать строку в формате ISO 8601. Также важно указать часовой пояс.

```
var ts = Date.parse("2017-10-11T00:56:20+03:00")/1000;
console.log(ts);
// Формат даты: ISO 8601, результат: 1507672580 (секунд)
```